# Wordpress: getting current page-id (acf) into a plugin-file.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i try to change the button-link inside a plugin (wp-domain-checker). 
Found the function in the file.php and placed a custom-field (acf: the_field(....)) instead. 
The goal: typing an individual url in each post/page custom field and the button will link to its own target, dependently on which page it appears. 
It works, if i put in the post-id manually, but it does not use the current post´s field if i dont´s set the post id, as it´s supposed to use. 
I tried several suggested functions (post-id from inside or outside the loop) - always empty.

```html
`//$cart_url = do_shortcode("[add_to_cart_url id='$additional_button_link']"); ///////THE ORIGINAL LINE
$cart_url = get_field('acfdomain1',2124);  ////MY CHANGE WORKS FINE so far...   `
```

But the "2124" should be replaced by the current post-id. 
That´s, what i tried:

1.

```html
`global $post;
$cart_url = get_field('acfdomain1',$post->ID);`
```

2.

```html
`$cart_url = get_field('acfdomain1');`
```

3.

```html
`$cart_url = get_field('acfdomain1',the_id());`
```

I also tried

```html
`$id = get_queried_object_id();
$cart_url = get_field('acfdomain1',$id);`
```

and this one:

```html
`$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
$current_post_id = url_to_postid( $url );`
```

Each result is full of emptiness.
Have spent several sessions with lots of hours meanwhile, just for this one topic. 
Can´t go on without it. 
Is there anyone who could help me a little bit, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is the very first in the documentation, but you didn't seem to have tried that:

`$id = get_the_ID(); $cart_url = get_field('acfdomain1',$id);`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/

Or you can also try:

`$queried_object = get_queried_object(); $id = $queried_object->ID; $cart_url = get_field('acfdomain1',$id);`

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi rank, 
thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately it didn´t work either. 
It seems as if the plugin prevents getting the id from "outside".

Comment: Have you tried to dumb the id variable to see if there is a value? maybe the problem is not the id, but get_field, because you are not using acf_head or something like this. Worth a try to check if Id is there. You could also show us the full code of your plugin, this can help.

Comment: sorry, i do not really know, how to dumb the id variable. 
I thought, it was ok, because it works with a direkt id and the acf-documentation proudly tells me, the custom fields work everywhere - obviously not. 
I try to post the whole code....

Comment: the drama starts in line 337

Comment: after setting the id variable, try: `function console_log( $id ){ echo '<script>'; echo 'console.log('. json_encode( $id ) .')'; echo '</script>'; } is the correct id in your console? you can see the console if you inspect your page with right click , inspector

Comment: So your get_field is not working correctly. Is it some kind of sub_field, inside a repeater or something?

Comment: i`m not sure, i just created it with the acf-plugin, no coding. The field appears in the admin-area below the content.

Comment: what about checkin it with team-viewer? I will pay for that of course

Comment: Ok, did you put the field inside of a group? This would be ok for be, but in the next 24 hours I am not at my pc, just with smartphone. you could show us a screenshot of how you created the field, so I can see if it is inside of something, so you have to access it some other way.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the edit screen of your acf field group? So you go to the acf plugin screen, select the field group and send a screenshot of this? I need to see if you field is inside a group or repeater, because then you will have to use a while clause and get_sub_field to retrieve the value of your field.

Comment: Maybe, this will help:

Comment: https://leloo.de/screenshot-3.jpg 

If i put the content of $cart_url direct into the link in line 353, it does show the post-id, 
but not the field-content. 
I also found the same problem in stackoverflow and changed the hook for the first function inside the plugin from "init" to "acf/init", "acf/save_post" and "acf_post" as suggested. Seemed to work for the others, but not for me.

Comment: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/use-get_field-in-other-plugin-to-get-a-custom-post-field/

Comment: Ok, much better to see on large screen. I don't really get your setting. You have a custom field set for a page, where you insert the end of an url with an ID at the end (is this the id of your current page? field-backend.jpg number 3155) What is this page? Do you have this field on every page? In your screenshot-acf.jpg you can go to the top right "ansicht anpassen" and check the "feldschlüssel". With this, you can try to access your field, maybe it helps. But you need to make sure that every page you want to show the value has set this field.

Comment: In your screenshot-3.jpg you use $_POST['item_id'] for the id, so you are getting it from an input field. This shows the correct id of the current viewing page? Strange... Just to make sure: You can only get the meta fields by the page ids, if the pages have this field value set. If not, it can not get any content. If you want all pages to have the same field value (i.e. because you add the $id by hand after the url string), then you can access it with the static id, because it is not changed between pages.

Comment: 3155 ist the woocommerce product-id. The domainchecker puts the chosen domain into a specified product. 
Yes, the field is on every page. 
With feldschlüssel it is the same issue.

Comment: Yes, $_POST['item_id'] shows correct id of current page. I got that from the same php-file of the plugin. So i don´t know, where the input-field is set. It wasn´t me.

Comment: You have a huuge plugin there with lots of code. What exactly is this plugin, what are you using it for, maybe you can overwrite with code in functions.php without manipulating the plugin file itself? Otherwise, In my oppinion, the place to edit how a single product looks like, would be in the single-product template file. But I guess you use this plugin for creating your product views...with product templates I could help you with some guidance if it is is an option for you. Sorry I can't help you with the plugin.

Comment: Hi, did it menawhile. 
I´ve built my own button that gets the acf-field as first part and the input-field of the domain-checker as second part of the url using javascript. 
Days of research and tries for 10 lines of code. Probably not the most elegant way, but it works. Thank you very much for having a look at it!